# How do I override the auto-generated getter of a public variable?

Tags: solidity

Example code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Guests {
    struct Person {
        string name;
        uint favNo;
    }
    Person[] public people;

    constructor() {
        people.push(Person("John", 56));
        people.push(Person("Emilia", 1337));
    }

    function getPeople(uint _index) public view returns (string memory, uint) {
        require (_index < people.length, "person does not exist.");
        return (people[_index].name, people[_index].favNo);
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint _favNo) public {
        people.push(Person(_name, _favNo));
    }
}
```

It ends up having two getters for the people variable:

[image]

I would like there to be only one, but having the "people" function name, therefore "getPeople" would somehow override the auto-generated getter. I guess that I'd start by making "people" private, but I don't know how to continue afterwards.

Comment: What is the purpose of `people` being public while you have your customized getter?  I think you may consider setting the  `people` variable private, it will work well.

Comment: @minhhn2910 Issue will then be having a variable (even private) having the same name as a function, this is not possible as you can't, at compilation time, know if it refers to the storage variable or the function pointer.

Comment: You set people as private and use getpeople as the function for reading it. There will be no “people” function generated by the compiler if you set it private. If you still want to use people function name then just rename your variable: private _people.

Comment: Wow yeah @minhhn2910, I should have thought of that. Just rename people to something else, make it private, and then I could name the function "people".

Answer (score 0):

Solidity does not support 2 storage variables with same name, so use different name while creating new functions like getPerson.

```
function getPerson(uint _index) public view returns (Person memory) {
    return people[_index];
}
```

override in solidity is possible at diff scenario like : abract contract functions can be declared virtual, later can be override in child contract

```
//parent abstract
abstract contract Feline {
    function utterance() public virtual returns (bytes32);
}

//child
contract Cat is Feline {
    function utterance() public override returns (bytes32) { return "miaow"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the same name for a global variable and a function, which is not possible (function are pointers - see the second example from the docs for instance https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html?highlight=function%20pointer#function-types), this would then mean 2 variables with the same name which is not possible as it would create confusion/shadowing.